# Optimization of a cypher query which deletes duplicate relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete a few duplicate relationships that got created between the same nodes. For example, node A is connected to node B with relationship R two times. Hence I have to delete one relationship. To do that I have written a query like this:

```
MATCH p = ()-[r:relationship]->()
WITH r.id AS id, collect(r) AS branches WHERE size(branches) > 1
FOREACH (n IN tail(branches) | DELETE n)
```

My question is whether I should use `DETACH DELETE`, or is a simple `DELETE` ok? Or in this case will `DETACH DELETE` and `DELETE` both do the same work?

In addition, please suggest how I can optimize this query!! Since there are millions of records to be deleted.

I have tried using both the `DELETE` clause and the `DETACH DELETE` clause, seems both worked the same. Note: I am using Neo4j version 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete is ok!

DETACH DELETE is a shorter way of doing a delete relationship then delete node. So instead of doing two steps of Delete node then Delete relationship, we use DETACH DELETE in one go.

For relationship, you are NOT detach(ing) it from a node, you simply deleting it. So using detach is not needed but neo4j will flag it as an error if you do DETACH DELETE for a relationship.  It understands the redundancy and deletes it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`DETACH DELETE` will delete *all* relationships attached to a given node before deleting that node. In your case, you are deleting specified relationships, so the `DETACH` keyword has no effect.

As you are using Neo4j 3.5, you could use the following as an optimized version of your query—assuming you have apoc installed:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (n)-[r:R]->(m)
     WHERE exists((n)-[r]->(m)<-[:R {id: r.id}]-(n))
     WITH r.id AS id, tail(collect(r)) AS branches
     UNWIND branches AS branch
     RETURN branch",
    "DELETE branch",
    {batchSize: 10000, parallel: true}
)
```

Using `r.id` as the grouping key works because its value is the same for all relationships that are duplicates of each other. The `exists` also assumes that the duplicate relationships have the same source and target nodes.

If you are on Neo4j 5, you could do a safer batched version of the above with `CALL IN TRANSACTIONS`:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:R]->(m) 
WHERE EXISTS { (n)-[r]->(m)<-[:R {id: r.id}]-(n) }
WITH r.id AS id, tail(collect(r)) AS branches
UNWIND branches AS branch
CALL { 
    WITH branch
    DELETE branch
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 10000 ROWS
```

Comment: In my relationship there many attributes, but I'd column is on the unique column which tells us whether the data is duplicate or not. If multiple relationship has same I'd then those relationships are duplicate.

Comment: Also in your optimized query you have mentioned size(branches)>0.. should it be 0 or it should be 1, since I have to delete the all the relationship keeping only One relationship as intact?

Comment: I see your code is considering all the records which are not even duplicates

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to use the fact that the id of relationships identifies the duplicates, and to explain that to anyone who doesn't know your data.

Comment: The branches is the tail of the result of `collect`, so if it have size > 0, we have duplicates. It's redundant with the exists. I will remove it.

Comment: I've added an exists predicate that will only return relationships that have duplicates. It exploits the fact that relationships are traversed only once i.e. it only has a solution if there is at least two relationships with the type R and the same id.

Comment: Can we put iterateList:true and parallel:false ? {batchSize: 10000, iterateList:true,parallel: false}

Comment: It's an allowed combination in the configuration, but as each operation is simple and independent from the others, I don't see what advantage it would give.

Comment: Thanks. But while running the query  I encountered an error like " Procedure call inside query doesn't support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using 'Yield'  instead)

Comment: I have added yield after the last statement as {batchSize: 10000, parallel: true} yield batches and it ran fine. Just wanted to confirm will it impact anything?

Comment: I am thinking to make the parallel false since there will be other process running which will use apoc iterate procedure and I don't want the performance to go down for making one parallel true. What you suggest!